# putting thread to sleep with Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, sleep

I wrote a program which is running at a server and listening on some ports. Since most of the time it has nothing to do, I set up a thread which prevents the program from stopping.

My solution looks like the following:

```
Thread mainThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                // run program continuously
                while ( true ) {
                    try {
                        // since we aren't doing anything, the thread can sleep
                        Thread.sleep( Long.MAX_VALUE );
                    }
                    catch ( InterruptedException e ) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } );

        mainThread.start();
```

My question is: 
Could the constant **Long.MAX_VALUE** be problematic and cause an error? I want to run the program all the time, so in my opinion the thread does not need to do anything. The easiest solution so far, is to put it to (very, very deep) sleep (the milisecond value translates roughly to 146.235.600 years).

Comment: "*Since most of the time it has nothing to do, I set up a thread which prevents the program from stopping.*" => this is not very clear. Why would your program stop?

Comment: This isn't really a sane thing to do. If you don't want your program to exit, simply don't exit. A thread that is blocked on IO uses approximately 0 CPU.

Comment: @assylias It might (will!) stop if all of the other threads are `daemon` threads.

Comment: @vikingsteve in which case an easier solution would be to make them non-daemon, wouldn't it?

Comment: Unless you put your server listening code inside of the run method this thread has no effect on server listening and carrying out requests.

Comment: @assylias easier? perhaps. right approach? i'm not so sure. he may not have control over how the other threads are started (for example, `hazelcast` threads). (edit: in any case, `Thread.setDaemon(true)` can't seem to be used after the thread has been started)

Comment: The program listens for telephone calls and uses a JNI Interface and a framework provided by the manufacturer of the hardware. The provided example code uses a worse solution than mine: System.out.println("Press any key to terminate");
            try
            {
                inChar = System.in.read();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error reading from user");
            }

Comment: @RobertSchröder if you set a breakpoint on one of the lines in the example code and look at the other jvm threads, are they all `daemon` threads?

Comment: @RobertSchröder, why are you worried the program will stop?

Comment: @vikingsteve I guess I would see something which is called "daemon" instead of "thread" in the eclipse debug window? If so then no, they are normal threads.
The moment a call occures, a new thread is started which is handling the call. The instantiation is done by framework. If I don't put some "blocking code" (as suggested by the manufacturer) into the program just starts, processes the setup functions and stops.

Comment: @RobertSchröder I dont know how to look at it in Eclipse since I use intelliJ, but I need to dig in and look at the thread details to see if it is `daemon` or not. I think one of 2 things is happening here - either all the other threads are daemon threads, or they are just slow to start up. What happens if you just wait for (say) 5 seconds (without an endless loop) - does your code still exit?

Answer (score 1):

A multithreaded program will continue running as long as there is one thread still running or blocked. It is not the case that your program will exit just because your original thread exits. Your program presumably has a thread waiting for a connection to the port, so you do not need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly, there's no reason to think that sleeping for any amount of (positive) time, including, `Long.MAX_VALUE`, will behave any different than how you expect it to.

As to whether you need to do this, I'd echo other's comments that it's probably not the nicest thing to do from a design perspective and there's most likely much better architectural decisions that could be made to avoid such a fudge (such as making daemon threads non-daemon if you're looking to stop the application from exiting.) However, technically speaking, yes - the thread should just go to sleep for the best part of a couple of centuries.

Answer (score 0):

Robert, if we read about [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class, we see:

> When a Java Virtual Machine starts up, there is usually a single non-daemon thread (which typically calls the method named main of some designated class). The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - All threads that are not daemon threads have died, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

It seems that your application will always shut down without some form of 'keep-alive' mechanism because the threads launched in the framework you are using are all `daemon` threads.

The simple way to prevent this, like you have done, is to keep a single non-daemon thread alive and running.

The code you posted, as others have pointed out, seems a little "simple", but technically there is nothing wrong with it.

Firstly may I suggest to simplify it a litte - remove the superfluous use of `new Runnable()` and remove the call to `e.printStackTrace()`.

With regards to using `Long.MAX_VALUE` as an argument to Thread.sleep, as others have commented, that's completely fine. However it would be better with some sort of regular "health check" so that if the framework you are using suddenly crashes or exits then so will your main thread.

Here's what I suggest:

```
    Thread mainThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // check if application is healthy at regular intervals
            while ( myApplication.isHealthy() ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep( 30 );
                } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
                    // ignore this, or log at DEBUG level
                }
            }
        }
    };
    mainThread.start();
```

With regards to improving the mechanism or finding another way to do this, I briefly looked at the following alternatives, none of which bore fruit.

1. BlockingQueue - other high-level concurrency objects can also "block" indefinitely, but they often also throw `InterruptedException` and are certainly less clear than `Thread.sleep`
2. ShutdownHook - shutdown hooks wont stop the jvm from stopping if all the remaining threads are daemon (as is the case)
3. Make another thread non-daemon - whilst you can easily find other running threads, it is not possible to call `setDaemon(false)` on a thread once it has started.

In summary, given the circumstances, what you are doing is fine - and you could think about checking your framework is still healthy at regular intervals if you can.